# Logout of Github using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, github, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that will always have a current user who is logged in to GitHub. In order to switch users, I want to have a log out button in my extension that logs the current user out.

I've tried simply

```
chrome.windows.create({'url':'https://github.com/logout'})
```

Which takes me to the GitHub logout page but there is still a confirmation that the user would have to click on to successfully logout. I would like to be able to log the user out in the background or at a minimum, without them having to click on an additional confirmation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Solution

When I called https://github.com/logout from an external page it showed a form with a submit/confirm button to logout. The form doesn't have an id or class but I managed to submit it using

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1].submit();
```

Of course, this isn't ideal since it will break if github changes the layout of their logout page. Also, there is a delay between when the page is loaded and the form is submitted which isn't very user friendly. I'll update here if I find a better solution

Comment: Excellent feedback +&, more accurate than my answer. don't forget you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted it. I would still love to see a way without opening a new window though...

Answer (score 2):

You can check if one of the two techniques mentioned here works for you:

- "[How to automatically click a confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575047/6309)": overriding the `window.confirm` function
- "[Auto Click for JavaScript confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287685/6309)": inserting dummy function `showConfirm()` at the top of the header of the `Browser.Document` which overwrites/suppress the original function `showConfirm()`.

Even if the names of the methods differ in the Github confirmation page, the idea remains: if you can somehow override/silence the confirmation method, you can skip past that step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have been more clear. It's not a confirmation dialog. It's a form on the page with a confirmation button that shows up when you navigate to https://github.com/logout from an external page. I guess I need to figure out a way to submit the form when the window loads. I tried using an XMLHttpRequest to POST to the page but GitHub returned a 422 unproccessable entity error

Comment: Your links weren't really relevant (my fault) but they lead me down the right path. Thanks. Upvoted for the help.